# Simple YACC grammar with problems

Tags: parsing, yacc

I want to implement a simple YACC parser, but I have problems with my grammar:

```
%union {
    s       string
    b       []byte
    t       *ASTNode
}

%token AND OR NOT
%token<s> STRING
%token<b> BYTES

%type<t> expr

%left AND
%left OR
%right NOT

%%

expr: '(' expr ')'              {{ $$ = $2 }}
    | expr AND expr             {{ $$ = NewASTComplexNode(OPND_AND, $1, $3) }}
    | expr AND NOT expr         {{ $$ = NewASTComplexNode(OPND_AND, $1, NewASTComplexNode(OPND_NOT, $4, nil)) }}
    | NOT expr AND expr         {{ $$ = NewASTComplexNode(OPND_AND, NewASTComplexNode(OPND_NOT, $2, nil), $4) }}
    | expr OR expr              {{ $$ = NewASTComplexNode(OPND_OR, $1, $3) }}
    | STRING                    {{ $$ = NewASTSimpleNode(OPRT_STRING, $1) }}
    | BYTES                     {{ $$ = NewASTSimpleNode(OPRT_BYTES, $1) }}
    ;
```

Cam someone explain me why it gives me these errors?:

```
rule expr:  NOT expr AND expr  never reduced
1 rules never reduced

conflicts: 3 reduce/reduce
```

Comment: Delete the 3rd rule and then modify 4th to be `NOT expr`. You should be able to invert *any* expression.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need my grammar to not accept constructions like: `NOT expr`, `NOT expr  OR expr`. The `NOT` operator should apply only to operands of `AND` and shouldn't be both `NOT`, like `NOT expr AND NOT expr`.

Comment: @saa: that requirement should be included in your question. Also, it needs to be clearer. Do you really mean to ban `NOT a AND NOT b AND c` but allow `c AND NOT a AND NOT b`? Or is your intention that a conjunction of multiple terms include at least one positive term (so that both of the above should be accepted.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a comment, it is clarified that the requirement is that:

> The `NOT` operator should apply only to operands of `AND` and [the operands] shouldn't be both `NOT`.

The second part of that requirement is a little odd, since the `AND` operator is defined to be left-associative. That would mean that

```
a AND NOT b AND NOT c
```

would be legal, because it is grouped as `(a AND NOT b) AND NOT c`, in which both `AND` operators have one positive term. But rotating the arguments (which might not change the semantics at all) produces:

```
NOT b AND NOT c AND a
```

which would be illegal because the first grouping (`NOT b AND NOT c`) contains two `NOT` expressions.

It might be that the intention was that any conjunction (sequence of `AND` operators) contain at least one positive term.

Both of these constraints are possible, but they cannot be achieved using operator precedence declarations.

Operator precedence can be used to resolve ambiguity in an ambiguous grammar (and `expr: expr OR expr` is certainly ambiguous, since it allows `OR` to associate in either direction). But it cannot be used to import additional requirements on operands, particularly not a requirement which takes both operands into account [Note 1]. In order to do that, you need to write out an unambiguous grammar. Fortunately, that's not too difficult.

The basis for the unambiguous grammar is what is sometimes called *cascading precedence* style; this effectively encodes the precedence into rules, so that precedence declarations are unnecessary. The basic boolean grammar looks like this:

```
expr: conjunction           /* Cascade to the next level */
    | expr OR conjunction
conjunction
    : term                  /* Continue the cascade */
    | conjunction AND term
term: atom                  /* NOT is a prefix operator */
    | NOT term              /* which is not what you want */
atom: '(' expr ')'
    | STRING
```

Each precedence level has a corresponding non-terminal, and the levels "cascade" in the sense that each one, except the last, includes the next level as a unit production.

To adapt this to the requirement that `NOT` be restricted to at most one operand of an `AND` operator, we can write out the possibilities more or less as you did in the original grammar, but respecting the cascading style:

```
expr: conjunction
    | expr OR conjunction
conjunction
    : atom                     /* NOT is integrated, so no need for 'term' */
    | conjunction AND atom
    | conjunction AND NOT atom /* Can extend with a negative */
    | NOT atom AND atom        /* Special case for negative at beginning */
    
atom: '(' expr ')'            
    | STRING
```

The third rule for `conjunction` (`conjunction: conjunction AND NOT atom`) allows any number of `NOT` applications to be added at the end of a list of operands, but does not allow consecutive `NOT` operands at the beginning of the list. A single `NOT` at the beginning is allowed by the fourth rule.

If you prefer the rule that a conjunction has to have at least one positive term, you can use the following very simple adaptation:

```
expr: conjunction
    | expr OR conjunction
conjunction
    : atom                     /* NOT is integrated, so no need for 'term' */
    | conjunction AND atom
    | conjunction AND NOT atom
    | negative AND atom        /* Possible initial list of negatives */
negative                       /* This is not part of the cascade */
    : NOT atom
    | negative AND NOT atom
atom: '(' expr ')'            
    | STRING
```

In this variant, `negative` will match, for example, `NOT a AND NOT b AND NOT c`. But because it's not in the cascade, that sequence doesn't automatically become a valid expression. In order for it to be used as an expression, it needs to be part of `conjunction: negative AND atom`, which requires that the sequence include a positive.

#### Notes

1. The `%nonassoc` precedence declaration can be used to reject chained use of operators from the same precedence level. It's a bit of a hack, and can sometimes have unexpected consequences. The expected use case is operators like `<` in languages like C which don't have special handling for chained comparison; using `%nonassoc` you can declare that chaining is illegal in the precedence level for comparison operators.

   But `%nonassoc` only works within a single precedence level, and it only works if all the operators in the precedence level require the same treatment. If the intended grammar does not fully conform to those requirements, it will be necessary -- as with this grammar -- to abandon the use of precedence declarations and write out an unambiguous grammar.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you very much.

Comment: Indeed, `NOT ` should be restricted to at most one operand of an `AND `.

Comment: @saa: OK. It still seems strange to me. Why do you allow only one of those two ways of writing the conjunction of `a`, `NOT b` and `NOT c`? Your AST can certainly handle either of them. Either way, it would be good to edit your question to make the requirement explicit.

Comment: Yes, I should have provided all the details -- sorry. I want to make a DB query language, and it should not allow constructions like `NOT x` because will return a lot of results. But `NOT x AND y`  can be handled because I can first query for `y`, then for `x` and remove all the results of `x` from `y`.

Comment: @saa: if you have `NOT a AND NOT b AND c`, you can still do the query for `c` first; it's easy enough to sort a list of conjoined queries so that the positive ones come first. On the other hand, `NOT a AND NOT b` is the same as `NOT (a OR b)`; if you think that positive queries are more manageable, you can make all your queries positive and do the complements during evaluation. Anyway, good luck with 5he project.

Comment: My DB is actually an index on file content with millions of indexed files. The query language should not allow `NOT word` because will be a lot of files returned. But in a conjunction with at least one positive operand `NOT` can be used because I can make a pre-filter by the positive operand. It is a set difference.

Comment: The index don't allow `NOT` queries. A `NOT word` actually queries the index for `word`, returning all the hashes of the files that contain the word `word` and then I should take all the other indexed files and remove the ones that contain the word `word`. But in a conjunction like `NOT word1 AND word2`, I should only remove the files that contain `word1` from the list of files that contain `word2`. So `NOT (a OR b)`  should not be valid -- I don't have fast method to query for files that don't contain a specific sequence.

Comment: During the parsing I build an AST which I evaluate to get the results. So for a query like `NOT a AND NOT b AND c`, the AST should look like `AND(NOT a, AND(NOT b, c))`, so the `AND` operator should be right associative or the grammar unambiguous, right?

Comment: It would be nice to allow both `NOT a AND NOT b AND c` and `a AND NOT b AND NOT c`, but the conjunction that contain the positive term should be evaluated first in both cases and I don't think this is possible without modifying/traversing the AST after it is generated.

Comment: @saa: a good start is to construct the conjunction nodes in the right order. That is, `negative AND atom {{ $$ = NewASTComplexNode(OPND_AND, $3, $1) }}`. That guarantees that the leftmost node in a sequence of conjunctions is not negative.

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much for all the info.